# Reverting (Undo) main branch commits [normal & merged commits] but preserve the history

Tags: git

How can we revert commits that are pushed to remote and merged into remote main?

```
*   c4f28ad (HEAD -> revert-databricks-install, origin/main, origin/HEAD, main) Merged PR 3973: fix: updated the docker image version to 1.0.3
|\  
| * 028bc29 (origin/updated-chart-docker-version, updated-chart-docker-version) fix: updated the docker image version to 1.0.3
* | aa68a82 Merged PR 43966: feat: added pip install "superset[databricks]"
|\| 
| * 682bbce (origin/install-databrick-driver) feat: added pip install "superset[databricks]"
|/  
* 4c93166 Add my docker image
* 6905f6e + live script for live ms
* 787adc7 Add jujube
* 9e178b9 Customised image
* 803f755 Added confluent catalogue
* 2ceddc8 Added missing live lollies
```

How do I revert all my commits so that the latest commit is 4c93166? Basically I want to undo so that the HEAD & repo state is as it was at 4c93166:

```
*   c4f28ad (HEAD -> revert-databricks-install, origin/main, origin/HEAD, main) Merged PR 3973: fix: updated the docker image version to 1.0.3
|\  
| * 028bc29 (origin/updated-chart-docker-version, updated-chart-docker-version) fix: updated the docker image version to 1.0.3
* | aa68a82 Merged PR 43966: feat: added pip install "superset[databricks]"
|\| 
| * 682bbce (origin/install-databrick-driver) feat: added pip install "superset[databricks]"
```

Note:

- There are two merged commits and I can't make changes to main branch directly.
- I need to create a feature branch, revert my changes and then raise a PR

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create a new commit whose *content* is equal to that of 4c93166?

Comment: Yes @mkrieger1 - I updated the question to make more senses - let me know if it is not clear please. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to revert your local repository to the desired state (the "tree"), then reset the "commit pointer" to the latest point. This way you will have all files in the previous state but on the latest commit. You can now make a new commit here.

```bash
git reset --hard 4c93166
git reset --soft origin/main
git commit -m "Revert everything to 4c93166"
```

Comment: thanks - I get what the --hard reset is doing - bring HEAD to 4c93166 and undoing all other higher commits but why do we need --soft? is it to bring back the commit history?

Comment: @BuggyB You want to create a new commit on top of `origin/main` so it can be fast-forwarded. Otherwise you'll still run into another merge.

Comment: thanks - that worked for me - also good read for anyone interested: https://opensource.apple.com/source/Git/Git-26/src/git-htmldocs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt